# ROW_NUMBER Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-number

We have a store procedure for searching within joined Tables. We have a Production and Dev Sql servers. The store procedure runs fine on Production server, but on Dev SQL server, it takes more than 2 min to execute. I m considering ROW Number to be the root cause of the performance issue we are having on Dev server.

```
CREATE proc  sp_fullEmp 
@take int ,
@skip int 
as 

with main as (
select 
 dt.FirstName +' '+ dt.LastName [FullName],
 dt.[Location],
emp.FirstName + ' '+ emp.LastName [Manager],
dt.[ApplicationDate] 

from  ExtractedData dt 
left join ProcessTable tb
        left join Employee emp on emp.ID = tb.EmployeeID
 on td.ExtID = dt.ID),

searched as (select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER By FullName ASC) RN from main)

select * from searched where RN BETWEEN @skip AND @Take
```

Sample of same query is running on other Tables without any performance issue on both Dev and Production servers with a larger set of data.

What can be the root cause of this issue ?

Execution [Dev Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJ8kGmxhx)

Execution [Prod Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkYDqme2l)

Comment: Share your execution plans using [Paste The Plan @ brentozar.com](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) here are the instructions: [How to Use Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/).

Comment: No one can answer this without execution plans. If your dev and test server are different versions (i.e. 2012 vs 2016) they can have different optimizer and thus, execute the query differently. The servers can have different RAM, different processors... endless possibilities. Check the statistics. Check the indexes.

Comment: what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: you might want to look into `offset` and `fetch`. [Pagination with `offset / fetch` : A better way - Aaron Betrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/pagination-with-offset-fetch)

Comment: Sql server 2008 both prod and dev

Comment: Is your DEV server a lower-end machine / shared environment /  throttled down?

Comment: You also should consider not use the sp_ prefix, or even better no prefix at all. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: Dev server is a shared one . exec plan is attached

Comment: @SeanLange I tested a sample of the query   without  warpping the qquery into a procedure and the results were the same

Comment: I think you missed my point. It isn't about putting this in a procedure which I think you should. It is about the name of your procedure. It was not intended to be a solution here. And as posted your query is not even valid syntax. Your searched cte does not have a from clause.

Comment: @SeanLange thanks for flagiing  the missing part on the cte. COnsider the exec plan.. its the full query

Comment: There are lots of low hanging performance issues in here. Start with your splitter. Throw it in the trash and use a set based one. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings Next is all the variable checks. This is known as a catch all query and there are some serious performance issues with this type of query. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Comment: We need the plan for both dev and production environment.

Comment: @PeterHenell  i added Prod version as well

Comment: I think the problem should be related to  the Database alone. I have a cloned version of the Production DB on the Dev server. No performance issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem might be parameter sniffing.
SQL doesn't know what @Skip and @Take are going to be and this could be throwing the plan.

Its worth comparing the data in Prod & Dev - Often Dev data can be a lot more "skewy" especially if its being inserted manually.
Look at see what are the Avg, min and Max

Try sticking a with RECOMPILE on the stored proc and see if this helps.
Alternately - DBCC FREEPROCCACHE will empty the proc cache and create a new plan.

I just realized you are not partitioning your Row_Number() query - this means that in effect you are just running a TOP N query order by Fullname- seems strange as it will give random results based on the number of Extracts and employees